# Динамические одномерные массивы

Tags: c, память, динамические-массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0, size;
    printf("Input size of array: ");
    scanf(" %d", &size);
    int *a = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int)); /*ввод размерности массива*/
    int *b;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = (rand() % 99) + 1;
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        if ((a[i] / 2) % 2 == 1) {
            b = (int*)realloc(b, ++x * sizeof(int));
            b[x - 1] = a[i];
        } /*запись массива нужных элементов в новый массив*/
    }
    printf("\n\nSequence of double odd values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("\n%d", b[i]);
    } /*вывод массива*/
    return 0;

}
```

Программа вылетает сразу же после вывода начального массива.

Что я не так делаю? Может, я неправильно выделяю динамическую память?

Comment: А чем и как вы компилируете? Какая ошибка вываливается? Я попробовал ваш код в нескольких компиляторах - всё работает хорошо.

Comment: я работаю в code::blocks. ошибок никаких нет. но когда в циклах я добавлял free(элемент массива); то вываливалась ошибка (точнее предупреждение) warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что произойдет вот здесь

```
b = (int*)realloc(b, ++x * sizeof(int));
```

при **самом первом** выполнении этой строки? Что вы передаете в `realloc()`?

P.S. А ведь компилятор наверняка предупреждал :)

VC++, например, честно говорит:

> warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "b"

Comment: я понял. фух. нужно было переменной b присвоить значение NULL

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: А можно вопрос, почему тогда в gcc или clang нет предупреждений и программа работает без проблем?

Comment: не знаю. наверное, у меня плохой компилятор. почти никакой информации об ошибках не дает. нужно качать новый. кто что может посоветовать?

Comment: Думаю, что у вас просто предупреждения отключены (или выставлен низкий их уровень) - посмотрите в настройках проекта. Как именно это делается в code::blocks - не подскажу, я сним не работал.  Ну, а если ответ помог - не забудьте потом отметить как принятый.

Comment: @Axenow Работает без проблем - на то и UB, что может быть вообще все... Про предупреждения не скажу, но вот слет на GCC: https://ideone.com/exHUaW